# Setting up eMail on Google Cloud Platform eg. mydomainname.com

Tags: email, cloud, hosting, platform, google-cloud-platform

I have just moved my wordpress website from Hostgator to GCP. Everything went very smoothly. I chnaged my name servers with Godaddy, create some DNS zone stuff in GCP and all works well.

Now it is time to setup my emails for the same domain in Google Cloud Platform.

I assume this also inolves some DNS MX stuff, but I am unable to find a whole lot about the process.

Does Google Cloud have email hsoting? If anyone can give me a hint so I can dive deeper.

Thanks in advance.

Ross

Answer (score 0):

Google offers email service which you can sign up on https://gsuite.google.com

After you have signed up you need to start entering the mx record which are mentioned in https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en make sure you follow the records mentioned in the link even the priority will be vital.